# How to import stored procedures into VS 2015 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, database-project

I have a visual studio database project.

I also have a database connection showing my stored procedures.

I have several stored procedures that I need to bring into the project.

I'm looking for the easiest workflow (hopefully multi-select and / or drag n drop) that I can use to get the stored procedures included as sql files.

Drag and drop shows the copy modifier and looks active when I drag over a database project folder, but the drop doesn't seem to work.

Copy from the server explorer works, but paste is not available on the database project folder.

The context menus don't seem to have anything else I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct rout to keep your model and a database in sync with each other is to use the schema compare.

Go to the project in the solution explorer and right click.  Select schema compare to bring up a new tab.  In the top left you should see that the project is selected.  In the top right select the target database by choosing either an existing connection or creating a new one.  Database objects move from left to right (i.e. source to target) so if you are moving objects to your database, leave it as is otherwise click the little icon right between the two to swap the source and target - this will then allow you to update the model from the existing database schema.

Carefully select the objects you would like to pull into the model then click Update in the upper left menu, this will then pull those items from the source to the target.

Comment: I'd add that setting the compare options to eliminate unnecessary or unwanted changes would also be a good idea. You may also want to be careful with the "drop if not found" type options.  There's also an option to import scripts into the existing project. If you script out CREATE statements for all of those procs, you should be able to right-click the project and import from script.

Comment: Also worth adding that if this is something you'll use a lot, you can save the schema compare. It won't save as something visible in your project, but you can show hidden files and include it or add from another location. (Think it might be time to open a Connect ticket on that one.)